# custom html in page change in browser

Tags: html

When I'm editing a page and add the following code in the text window:

```
<div class="row">
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=55" target="_blank">
    <div class="basicBox col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2">
        Sistema de referencia
        <svg width="130" height="65" viewBox="0 0 130 65" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x='0' y='0' fill='none' width='130' height='65'/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=18" target="_blank"><code></code>
    <div class="basicBox col-sm-2">
        Vector Posición
        <svg width="130" height="65" viewBox="0 0 130 65" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x='0' y='0' fill='none' width='130' height='65'/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</a>
```

It changes to this in the browser:

```
<div class="row">
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=55" target="_blank">
    <div class="basicBox col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2">
        Sistema de referencia
        <svg width="130" height="65" viewBox="0 0 130 65" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="130" height="65"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
</a>
<p>
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=55" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=18" target="_blank"></a>
</p>
<div class="basicBox col-sm-2">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=18" target="_blank">
        Vector Posición
        <svg width="130" height="65" viewBox="0 0 130 65" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="130" height="65"></rect>
        </svg>
    </a>
</div>
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=18" target="_blank"></a>
<p>
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=18" target="_blank"></a>
</p>
```

All the tags are closed, someone know why this happend?

Comment: I doubt `<svg>` can be wrapped in an `a`, but a perfect solution is a link that overlays the `div`, smth like this http://pastebin.com/UiwY1LuB Or probably use an image (with src to n svg independent file) and link it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer posted in the commented by [Samuel Elh](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/70833/samuel-elh):

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="basicBox col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2" style="position:relative;">
        Sistema de referencia
        <svg width="130" height="65" viewBox="0 0 130 65" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x='0' y='0' fill='none' width='130' height='65'/>
        </svg>
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=55" target="_blank" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="basicBox col-sm-2" style="position:relative;">
        Vector Posición
        <svg width="130" height="65" viewBox="0 0 130 65" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x='0' y='0' fill='none' width='130' height='65'/>
        </svg>
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=18" target="_blank" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></a>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.row -->
```